# Change syntax styling of TinyMCE HTML Text Editor

Tags: tinymce, editor, visual-editor, wp-editor, post-editor

So I have customized the CSS display for the TinyMCE 'Visual Editor' by using this here:

```
/* Add Theme CSS to WP Content Editor
-------------------------------------------------- */
function wp_kit_editor_style() {
    add_editor_style( get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/styles/main.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wp_kit_editor_style' );
```

And that outputs my Theme CSS into the Visual Editor.

[image]

Is it possible to change the look of the 'Text Editor'? I do not like the look of the plain text editor, and would like to stylize it so it looks like [Atom](https://atom.io/), or [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

[image]

Closest thing I find to use is [PrismJS](http://prismjs.com/). Is there a way to hook into the Text Editor that we can pass custom CSS and JS?

Thanks.

Comment: For the record, I believe the text (HTML) editor which you are referring to is independent from TinyMCE. So your question title may be misleading...

Comment: Thanks... not sure what the title would be, so I just modified the title. Not sure how to word it properly, hopefully the images will do justice.